# jQuery UI draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a battleship game but I'm having a problem when I drop the div that represents a ship, it gets appended to the droppable box that is in the middle of the ship(can be seen in the screenshot) and what I need is to append it to the box that is on the further left or when the ship is vertical to the box that is on the top part of the ship.

In the next screenshot the ship when is dropped is being appended to the box 34 and what I need is to append it to the box 32.

[image]

I would appreciate some help, thanks in advance

Ps. the ships change direction on double click

this is my fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kronolynx/m4aa6vkd/)

```js
$(function () {
    var board = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        board += "<div class='seaBox' id='pos" + i + "'></div>";
    }
    $(".board").append(board);

    $('.ship').draggable({
      addClasses: false,
      containment: '.board',
      snap: ".seaBox",
      grid: [40, 40],
      revert: "invalid"

    });

        // on drop append ship
    $('.seaBox').droppable({
            hoverClass: "red",
      drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("droppable " + $(this).attr("id"));
      },
    });

    // change orientation
    $(".ship").dblclick(function () {

      var ship_id = $(this).attr("id");
      var height = $(this).css("height");
      var width = $(this).css("width");

      ship_id = ship_id.charAt(ship_id.length - 1 ) == 'V' ? ship_id.slice(0, -1) : ship_id + "V";

      $(this).css("height", width);
      $(this).css("width", height);
      $(this).attr("id", ship_id);

    });

    //example of setting ship 
    $('#pos11').append($('#cruiser'));
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color:lightgray;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.board {
  float:left;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: -50;
  width: 430px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 7px;
 }


.seaBox {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: .3px solid black;
}

#shipSelection {
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 272px;
  float: left;
}

#shipYard {
  height: 353px;
  padding: 35px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-image: asset-data-url('water.jpg');
}

/** ships **/

#draggable {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}


/** 5 cells **/

#aircraft {
  width: 200px;
  background: asset-data-url('shipLong.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

#aircraftV {
  background: asset-data-url('shipLongV.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
}

/** 3 cells **/

#cruiser {
  width: 120px;
  background: asset-data-url('ship3.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}
#cruiserV {
  background: asset-data-url('ship3v.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
}


/** 3 cells **/

#cruiser2 {
  width: 120px;
  background: asset-data-url('ship1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

#cruiser2V {
  background: asset-data-url('ship1v.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
  background-size:contain
}

/** 2 cells **/

#destroyer {
  width: 79px;
  background: asset-data-url('ship2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
  background-size:contain
}

#destroyerV {
  background: asset-data-url('ship2v.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
}

#destroyer2 {
  width: 79px;
  background: asset-data-url('ship4.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
  background-size:contain
}

#destroyer2V{
  background: asset-data-url('ship4v.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
}



.ship {
  position:absolute;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;

}






/** clear **/

.spacer{
  display: block;
  clear:both;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<div class="board">
</div>
<div id="shipSelection">
  <div id="shipYard">
    <div class="ship" id="aircraft"></div>
    <div class="spacer"> </div>
    <div class="ship" id="destroyer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"> </div>
    <div class="ship" id="cruiser"></div>
    <div class="spacer"> </div>
    <div class="ship" id="cruiser2"></div>
    <div class="spacer"> </div>
    <div class="ship" id="destroyer2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function () {
    var board = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        board += "<div class='seaBox' id='pos" + i + "'></div>";
    }
    $(".board").append(board);

    $('.ship').draggable({
      addClasses: false,
      containment: '.board',
      snap: ".seaBox",
      grid: [40, 40],
      revert: "invalid"

    });

        // on drop append ship
    $('.seaBox').droppable({
            hoverClass: "red",
      drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("droppable " + $(this).attr("id"));
      },
    });

    // change orientation
    $(".ship").dblclick(function () {

      var ship_id = $(this).attr("id");
      var height = $(this).css("height");
      var width = $(this).css("width");

      ship_id = ship_id.charAt(ship_id.length - 1 ) == 'V' ? ship_id.slice(0, -1) : ship_id + "V";

      $(this).css("height", width);
      $(this).css("width", height);
      $(this).attr("id", ship_id);

    });

    //example of setting ship 
    $('#pos11').append($('#cruiser'));
});
```

html

```
<div class="board">
</div>
<div id="shipSelection">
  <div id="shipYard">
    <div class="ship" id="aircraft"></div>
    <div class="spacer"> </div>
    <div class="ship" id="destroyer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"> </div>
    <div class="ship" id="cruiser"></div>
    <div class="spacer"> </div>
    <div class="ship" id="cruiser2"></div>
    <div class="spacer"> </div>
    <div class="ship" id="destroyer2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
  background-color:lightgray;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.board {
  float:left;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: -50;
  width: 430px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 7px;
 }


.seaBox {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: .3px solid black;
}

#shipSelection {
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 272px;
  float: left;
}

#shipYard {
  height: 353px;
  padding: 35px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-image: asset-data-url('water.jpg');
}

/** ships **/

#draggable {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}


/** 5 cells **/

#aircraft {
  width: 200px;
  background: asset-data-url('shipLong.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

#aircraftV {
  background: asset-data-url('shipLongV.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
}

/** 3 cells **/

#cruiser {
  width: 120px;
  background: asset-data-url('ship3.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}
#cruiserV {
  background: asset-data-url('ship3v.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
}


/** 3 cells **/

#cruiser2 {
  width: 120px;
  background: asset-data-url('ship1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

#cruiser2V {
  background: asset-data-url('ship1v.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
  background-size:contain
}

/** 2 cells **/

#destroyer {
  width: 79px;
  background: asset-data-url('ship2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
  background-size:contain
}

#destroyerV {
  background: asset-data-url('ship2v.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
}

#destroyer2 {
  width: 79px;
  background: asset-data-url('ship4.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
  background-size:contain
}

#destroyer2V{
  background: asset-data-url('ship4v.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0;
}



.ship {
  position:absolute;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;

}






/** clear **/

.spacer{
  display: block;
  clear:both;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: @Owlvark Thanks for editing my code but the draggables don't work on the "run code snippet"

Comment: What do you mean "handle" of the droppable..? droppables don't have a handle, only draggables does. And you're not at all using handle option. Can you rephrase your question explaining what you meant by handle..?

Comment: you are right, I meant the draggable. when the draggable is dropped it's appended to the droppable at the position of the handle, what I need is to append it from the left part of the draggable. I will make a capture of the screen in a moment and post it. thanks

Comment: please stop using the term handle. There is no such thing as handle for a droppable and it is really confusing since draggable has such a thing. The red thing is the entire droppabble itself, not just a part of it. you can just refer to it by "hovered droppable" or something. Because the red color is the entire droppable which is currently hovered

Comment: @TJ thanks for the feedback, you are right it was really confusing and I was using the words wrong.  I just edited it, I hope now it's clear, please let me know if it's ok now, thanks again

Comment: Sorry for the broken snippet - I have submitted a fixed version.